# Can AJAX submit credentials for Basic Authentication?

Tags: ajax, apache, forms, authentication, basic-authentication

This might be a little bit of a stretch, but let's just assume that we need it to work this way:

- I have an index.html file in the web root of a server. The javascript in that file needs to make an ajax request to /secure/ajax.php
- Everything in the /secure/ directory is protected using Basic Authentication
- I don't want to bother the user with logging in to the /secure/ section

Can I submit credentials for basic authentication with an AJAX request?

Comment: Not trivial as what you propose.
[How it works](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#basicworks)
Perhaps it could be done with Ajax.

Comment: thanks. any thoughts on doing it with ajax? i was assuming since the browser would be sending authentication credentials, with a header, that the form could be set up to do a similar thing. i'm not giving up, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader is your friend.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "username:password in base64")
```

you just need to convert username:password to base64